# Ember Data: preload relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

What I'm trying to do is very basic but I'm having very little luck...

Simply enough, I don't want to display a chunk of HTML until a certain Ember Data model property is fully loaded.

As you can see from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfkNp/4/), the parent model: `App.Person` gets loaded into the DOM and it also loads the 3 placeholders for its hasMany property `belts`.

It then executes the request to populate `App.Belt` and fills in the placeholders.

While this is usually ok, it makes a big mess of things when trying to build an SVG, for example. Since the surrounding `<svg>` tags will get appended to the DOM immediately and then some time down the track (once the asynchronous request returns data), the inner `svg` components will be added between the tags. This usually creates browser rendering errors.

**TL;DR**
In the example, how do I defer the `<h3>...</h3>` section of the template from being added to the DOM **until** the model data and its relationships (`belts`) are fully loaded? This way everything gets visually and physically added to the DOM at once.

**The JS:**

```
// Create Ember App
App = Ember.Application.create();

// Create Ember Data Store
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11,
    //Exagerate latency to demonstrate problem with relationships being loaded sequentially.
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({latency: 5000})
});


// Create parent model with hasMany relationship
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
    belts: DS.hasMany( 'App.Belt' )
});

// Create child model with belongsTo relationship
App.Belt = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr( 'string' ),
    parent: DS.belongsTo( 'App.Person' )
});

// Add Parent fixtures
App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Trevor",
    "belts" : [1, 2, 3]
}];

// Add Child fixtures
App.Belt.FIXTURES = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "leather"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "rock"
}, {
    "id" : 3,
    "type" : "party-time"
}];

// Set route behaviour
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('people');
  }
});
```

**The HTML/HBS:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Application</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="people">
    <h3>Don't load this header until every belt defined in App.Person.belts is loaded</h3>
    <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
        {{debugger}}
        <li>Id: {{id}}</li>
        <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
        <li>Belt types:
            <ul>
            {{#each belts}}
                <li>{{type}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

**The fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zfkNp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check for the controller.content.length and belts.isLoaded, See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSEpE/) for a solution.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="people">
    {{#if controller.ready}}
    <h3>Don't load this header until every belt defined in App.Person.belts is loaded</h3>
    {{/if}}
    <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
        {{debugger}}
        {{#if belts.isLoaded}}
        <li>Id: {{id}}</li>
        <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
        <li>Belt types:
            <ul>
            {{#each belts}}
                <li>{{type}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>


App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: null,        
    ready:function() {
        return this.get('content.length')>0        
    }.property('content.length')
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ken but that jsFiddle doesn't work. The header never loads.

Comment: Hey Ken, thanks for having another go but that header is still not being displayed to the DOM at the same time as the belts :/

Comment: The issue is no longer the code, remove the latency set on the adapter.